# How to write a mongoose query to filter subdocuments

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema called "Users" which has a "Roles" subdocument as one of its variables like so:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    roles: [ { type: Number, ref: 'Role' } ]
});

var RoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

I want to create a Mongoose query that will find all users with roles.names of "admin" or "owner". I've tried using this query, which I thought would work, but I don't get any users when I use the `where...in` part.

```
var roles = ["owner", "admin"];
User.find()
    .populate('roles')
    .where('roles.name').in(roles)
    .sort({'_id': 1})
    .exec(function (err, users) {
        res.send(users);
    });
```

Can someone tell me where my logic is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to query more than one collection with a single query. If `Role` was an embedded subdocument in `User` then you could do a query on `roles.name` but presently that's not supported because it's a separate collection that is referenced in `User`.

However, a workaround is to add another filter step after the query returns that manually filters out documents which don't have any roles that matched the populate criteria but first you need to use a match query in populate instead of where method:

```
var roles = ["owner", "admin"];
User.find()
    .populate('roles', null, { name: { $in: roles } } )
    .sort({'_id': 1})
    .exec(function (err, users) {
        users = users.filter(function(user){
            return user.roles.length;
        });
        res.send(users);
    });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Too bad there isn't a more elegant way to handle this, but this works. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonAddleman Mongoose has built functionality for what your trying to do. See my answer.

Comment: @chridam can you please suggest how i will apply pagination on this?

Answer (score -1):

This is built into Mongoose `populate()` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) . You can simply structure a query like this:

```
 var roles = ["owner", "admin"];
 User.find()
    .populate({
        path: 'roles',
        match: { name: { $in: roles }},
        select: 'name'
    })
    .sort({'_id': 1})
    .exec(function (err, users) {

        res.send(users);
    });
```

Comment: This would get me **all** of the users but only populate the "roles" field when the user was an owner or admin. That's not the functionality I want. I only want to get a user if he/she is an owner or admin. That's why the filter in @chridam's answer is correct.